# Spawning a new thread while importing

Tags: python, multithreading, import, restriction

Python's [`threading` documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code) states:

> Other than in the main module, an import should not have the side
>   effect of spawning a new thread and then waiting for that thread in
>   any way. Failing to abide by this restriction can lead to a deadlock
>   if the spawned thread directly or indirectly attempts to import a
>   module.

I'm looking for example code that demonstrates this restriction.

Comment: isn't this because module importing is in general not thread safe?

Comment: @DanD. - Actually the docs also say: `While the import machinery is thread-safe, there are two key restrictions on threaded imports due to inherent limitations...`

Comment: `threading` has two limitations re importing - I've asked a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456395/threaded-importing-while-interpreter-shuts-down)

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, a module that spawns a thread whose target tries to import `sys`:

```
from threading import Thread

def my_target():
    import sys

thread = Thread(target=my_target)
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

When the python interpreter is launched and an attempt to import the module above is made, it indeed freezes.