# Threaded importing while interpreter shuts down

Tags: python, multithreading, import, restriction

Python's [`threading` documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code) states:

> All import attempts must be completed before the interpreter starts
>   shutting itself down. This can be most easily achieved by only
>   performing imports from non-daemon threads created through the
>   threading module. Daemon threads and threads created directly with the
>   thread module will require some other form of synchronization to
>   ensure they do not attempt imports after system shutdown has
>   commenced. Failure to abide by this restriction will lead to
>   intermittent exceptions and crashes during interpreter shutdown (as
>   the late imports attempt to access machinery which is no longer in a
>   valid state).

I'm looking for example code that demonstrates this restriction.

Comment: `threading` has two limitations re importing - I've asked a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456389/spawning-a-new-thread-while-importing)